# ValueError: time data '2018-09-' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python-3.x, csv, datetime, google-colab

mi problema es el siguiente: tengo que trabajar con un archivo csv, extraer todos los datos de una columna que contiene más de 900k fechas en formato string. y pasarlas a formato datetime.
Lo hice sin problemas usando replit pero me piden presentar el trabajo en google colab y en colab me salta el error:
*ValueError: time data '2018-09-' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'*

```
with open('reviews.csv', encoding='utf-8') as Archivo: 
reader = csv.reader(Archivo)

reviews = [] #creamos lista para ir almacenando la cantidad de reviews mensuales.son 12 en total
for fila, [_, review_date] in enumerate(reader): # el _ pasa por alto la primera columna del .csv
  if fila != 0: #salteo la 1era fila
    reviews.append(review_date)
for i in reviews:
  conver = datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d')
print(conver)
```

A simple vista interpreto que a alguna de las 900mil celdas le pueda estar faltando el día (2018-09-?) y que por eso no lo toma pero realmente no sé cómo solucionarlo si es ese el caso. Y me llama la atención que en replit me funciona perfectamente

Comment: Que debería de hacer tu programa cuando se encuentra con ese caso? Además, no creo que el problema sea colab, si no que colab y replit tienen dos versiones distintas del archivo.

Comment: Hola Dante . La finalidad del programa es filtrar las fechas del cvs que estén entre julio de este año y julio del año pasado . Para eso las convierto de str a datetime y ahí es cuando me salta el error. Tanto en replit como en vscode me funciona pero en colab no . Cuando decís a dos versiones distintas del archivo, te referís al csv?

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero mi pregunta es más como: que debe de hacer tu programa (o una persona) cuando se encuentra con esa fecha incompleta? Debe ignorar el dia y solo darle atención al mes y al año?

Comment: Claro, el día es irrelevante. Sólo interesan mes y año

Comment: Cuales son los posibles formatos en los que puede venir la fecha? Además de '%Y-%m-%d' y '%Y-%m-'